# d3 chain methods for .on() events

Tags: d3.js, mouseevent, method-chaining

Thanks to the reusable table setted up with this help

[Updating an HTML table in d3.js using a reusable chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514776/updating-a-table-in-d3-js-using-a-reusable-chart)

I have a good reusable [D3.js](http://d3js.org) code, applied for example here:

http://ross.iasfbo.inaf.it/~gloria/web-examples/valencia/bright-stars.html

Initializing and calling it is simple:

```
var t1 = myreusabletable(); // initialization
t1.columns(["id","column","other_column"]) // column setup

d3.json("data.json",function(error,data){
    d3.select("body").datum(data).call(t1)
});
```

However, until now, event bindings
have to be pre-coded in the `myreusabletable()` function:

```
rows.on('mouseover', function(d){mouseover(d)});
```

and setted from outside

```
function mouseover(d){
  ...
}
```

**My question is:** how can I set up a method in `myreusabletable()` so that I can chain the `.on(event,function)`  from outside like that:

```
var t1 = myreusabletable(); // initialization
t1.columns(["id","column","other_column"]) // column setup
  .on("mouseover",function(d,i){...})  // event binding setup here
  .on("click",function(d,i){...}) // event binding setup here
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you tried `return this` or `that` in the end of the function inside of `on`? I clearly don't know if it would work but it is worth trying.

Comment: The fact is that `.on()` is a d3.js method, while the function called inside is a custom function that I program following my needs (`.on("mouseover",customfunction)` if I need it, and so on) so returning `this` makes no sense in this particular case.

Comment: Do you want the `on` listener to apply to the entire table or to individual elements (rows, cells, etc) within it?

Comment: I would like to apply it to the rows, or, in alternative, I would like to choose in a way like `t1.rows.on("mouseover",...)`,  `t1.cells.on("mouseclick",...)`