# How to select individual rows in a D3 table

Tags: d3.js

Currently learning D3 and I'm a bit confused with tables. I was able to find this code in the internet which creates a simple HTML table:

```
function tabulate(data, columns) {
var table = d3.select("#container").append("table"),
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");

// append the header row
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function(column) { return column; });

// create a row for each object in the data
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr");

// create a cell in each row for each column
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
        .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

return table;
}
```

And I have this as my JSON file:

```
[
 {"name": "John", "age": 11},
 {"name": "Jane", "age": 20},
 {"name": "Robert", "age": 35},
 {"name": "Meg", "age": 56},
 {"name": "Ryan", "age": 80},
 {"name": "Emma", "age": 11},
 {"name": "Dale", "age": 20},
 {"name": "Sam", "age": 35},
 {"name": "Belle", "age": 56},
 {"name": "Snow", "age": 80}
]
```

It's going to create a simple two-column table. Now my question is, how can I select individual rows? if I use selectAll ("tbody tr"), it will of course select all the rows. But if I use select("tbody tr"), it will only select the first one.

Please keep in mind that I'm a complete newbie at this. I learn mostly through reading and trial and error.

Comment: This post can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514776/updating-an-html-table-in-d3-js-using-a-reusable-chart

Comment: You could also give each row a unique id using, so something like `.attr("id", function (d) { return d.name; })`.  Then you could select using the id, like `d3.select("#John")`